# Form fields are disabled when i pass edit into a bootsrap data attribut. How do i make the fields editable

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, disabled-input

For fields are disabled when i pass edit into a bootstrap data attribut. How do i make the fields editable. How do i enable the text field. the values is dynamically passed, but the fields are disabled. I need help, I don't have a clue to it.

FIRST STEP

I have a table that gets details from MySQL when data is fetched from the db

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.divDisplayTerm').addClass('loader');
     $.get('actionTermsearch.php', function(data){
             $('.divDisplayTerm').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
             $('.divDisplayTerm').removeClass('loader');
        });

        $('.autosuggestterm').keyup(function() {

        var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
            if (!search_term.length){
                $.get('actionTermsearch.php', function(data){
                    $('.divDisplayTerm').html(data).fadeIn("fast");
                });
            }else{
                $.get('actionTermsearch.php', {search_term: search_term}, function(data){
                    $('.divDisplayTerm').html(data).fadeIn("fast");
                });
            }
        });
});
```

The above jQuery loads the query from

```
<?php

include_once('../includes/dc_conect.php');

if((!isset($_GET['search_term'])==true) and (!isset($_GET['search_term'])!=NULL)){

    $sqlSession = "select * from sessions where id='$id' ";
    $resultSession=mysql_query($sqlSession, $link) or die (mysql_error());
    $dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession);
    $countSession=mysql_num_rows($resultSession);

    if($countSession > 0){
      do{
          $sessionID=$dbfieldSession['sn'];
       echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='checked_id[]' class='checkboxSession' value=".$dbfieldSession['sn']. "/></td>";        
            echo "<td>".$dbfieldSession['session_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>"; $sessionStatus=$dbfieldSession['session_status']; 
            if($sessionStatus==1){
                echo 'Current Session';
                }else
                {
                    echo 'Not Current Session';
                    }            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>"; 
            echo "<a href='#' class='edit-record' data-id=".$sessionID."><span class='btn btn-primary'><i class='icon-pencil'>".' Edit '."</i></span></a>&nbsp;";  

                  echo "<a href='#' class='delete-record' data-id=".$sessionID."><span class='btn btn-danger'><i class='icon-trash'>".' Remove '."</i></span></a>&nbsp;";  


                             echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       }while($dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is no record found!";
        }

}
else
{    $search_term=$_GET['search_term'];

        $sqlSession = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_name LIKE '%$search_term%'";
        $resultSession=mysql_query($sqlSession, $link) or die (mysql_error());
        $dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession);
        $countSession=mysql_num_rows($resultSession);

    if($countSession > 0){
      do{
          $sessionID=$dbfieldSession['sn'];
       echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='checked_id[]' class='checkboxSession' value=".$dbfieldSession['sn']. "/></td>";        
            echo "<td>".$dbfieldSession['session_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>"; $sessionStatus=$dbfieldSession['session_status']; 
            if($sessionStatus==1){
                echo 'Current Session';
                }else
                {
                    echo 'Not Current Session';
                    }            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>"; 
            echo "<a href='#' class='edit-record' data-id=".$sessionID."><span class='btn btn-danger'><i class='icon-pencil'>".' Edit '."</i></span></a>&nbsp;";   

                             echo "<a href='#' class='delete-record'><span class='btn btn-primary'><i class='icon-trash'>".' Remove '."</i></span></a>";     

                             echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       }while($dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is no record found for the filter!";
        }
}
?>
```

Using the jquery, i pulled the table with the search feature as shown in this screen shot

[image]

SECOND PHASE
on the

```
echo "<a href='#' class='edit-record' data-id=".$sessionID."><span   class='btn btn-danger'><i class='icon-pencil'>".' Edit '."</i></span></a>&nbsp;";
```

i dynamically pass this variables to the modal shown below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Session</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        </div>         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery that sends the dynamic plus the editSession.php into the modal

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-record', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.modal-body').html('');
    $('.modal-body').addClass('loader');
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

    $.post('editSession.php', {
        id: $(this).attr('data-id')
    }, function (html) {
        $('.modal-body').removeClass('loader');
        $('.modal-body').html(html);   
});
```

Now see editSession.php

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal" id="signupForm" method="post" action="">
    <h3>Edit Session </h3>
    <div class="control-group ">
    <label for="label5" class="control-label">Session Name: </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input value="<?php echo $sessionnameEdit; ?>" name="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group ">
    <label for="label5" class="control-label">Choose status: </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select  name="session_status">
               <option value="">-Session status--</option>
               <option value="1">Set as current session</option>
               <option value="0">Not current session</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_status">Update Status</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

See the scree grab when modal shows up

So the modal loads with the form fields disabled. i cant get a user to type inside.

[image]

Comment: What is the content of `$sessionnameEdit` ? Is it the modal?

Comment: Can you show us `editSession.php` content?